# Как удалить пары объектов из массива?(не удаление дубликатов)

Tags: javascript

Я перерыл весь интернет и не нашел решение, я перечитал все страницы на стековефлоу, хабре
Есть варианты только удаление ДУБЛИКАТОВ, что мне не подходит(мне не надо оставлять одно уникальное значение)

```
let data = [
{'time': '21:30'},
{'time': '21:30'},
{'time': '21:30'},
{'name': 'ivan'},
{'name': 'ivan'}
]
```

я хочу удалять элементы из массива если они одинаковые
если у меня в массиве есть {'name': 'ivan'} и ему соответствующая пара {'name': 'ivan'}, оба удаляются
ожидаю на выходе массив

```
let data = [
{'time': '21:30'},
]
```

Comment: А разве `{'time': '21:30'}` не повторяется? И приведите код с вашей попыткой решить задачу.

Comment: {'time': '21:30'} имеет пару {'time': '21:30'}
третьей значение {'time': '21:30'} не имеет пары, следовательно должно остаться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У метода с JSON.stringify есть некоторые ограничения. Например, если свойства объектов идут не в одном порядке, то сравнение вернёт false.

```js
 let data = [
    {'time': '21:30'},
    {'time': '21:30'},
    {'time': '21:30'},
    {'name': 'ivan'},    
    {'name': 'ivan'},
    {
      'a':'x',
      'name': 'ivan'
    },
    {      
      'name': 'ivan',
      'a':'x'
    }
  ]
  
let new_data = data.reduce((s,e,i,a) => {   
   if (!s.some(el => JSON.stringify(e) == JSON.stringify(el))) {
   if (a.filter(item => JSON.stringify(item) == JSON.stringify(e)).length%2 != 0) s.push(e);    
    return s;
   }  
   return s;
},[])

console.log(new_data)

console.log(selection(data))

function selection(arr) {
  var res = [];
  var index = [];

  for (i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
    for (j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++)
      if (!index.includes(i) && !index.includes(j) && isEqual(arr[i], arr[j]))
        index.push(i, j);

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    if (!index.includes(i) && !index.includes(i))
      res.push(arr[i]);

  return res
}

function isEqual(object1, object2) {
  const props1 = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object1);
  const props2 = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object2);

  if (props1.length !== props2.length) {
    return false;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < props1.length; i += 1) {
    const prop = props1[i];
    const bothAreObjects = typeof(object1[prop]) === 'object' && typeof(object2[prop]) === 'object';

    if ((!bothAreObjects && (object1[prop] !== object2[prop])) ||
      (bothAreObjects && !isEqual(object1[prop], object2[prop]))) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Боже, когда-нибудь и я научусь писать такие гениальные решения............. спасибо

Comment: На здоровье! :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно так попробовать. Проверяем на четность количество одинаковых элементов. Если нечетное, значит элемент попадает в новый массив.

```js
let data = [
  {'time': '21:30'},
  {'time': '21:30'},
  {'time': '21:30'},
  {'name': 'ivan'},
  {'name': 'ivan'},  
]

let new_data = data.reduce((s,e,i,a) => {   
   if (!s.some(el => JSON.stringify(e) == JSON.stringify(el))) {
   if (a.filter(item => JSON.stringify(item) == JSON.stringify(e)).length%2 != 0) s.push(e);    
    return s;
   }  
   return s;
},[])

console.log(new_data)
```

Comment: Это работает, спасибо огромное, я видел, что вы написали до этого решение и оно не совсем правильно работало. Очень надеялся, что вы вернетесь, спааааааааааааасибо, часов 5 убил, что бы найти решение

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете обьявить новый пустой массив, далее сделать итерацию по старому объекту на признак нахождения пары для каждого элемента -> Если пара есть - записать в новый массив объектов, а в старом удалить эти 2 объекта

Answer (score 0):

Хочу тоже предложить пару вариантов. Первое решение на основе хеш-таблицы. Заполняем таблицу и следом простейший фильтр по четности. Быстрее не могу себе представить:

```js
let data = [
  {'time': '21:30'},
  {'time': '21:30'},
  {'time': '21:30'},
  {'name': 'ivan'},
  {'name': 'ivan'},  
];

let hashes = {};

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  let key = JSON.stringify(data[i]);
  hashes.hasOwnProperty(key) ? hashes[key] ^= 1 : hashes[key] = 1;
}

let result = data.filter(e => hashes[JSON.stringify(e)]-- > 0);

console.log(result);
```

Второе решение основано на сравнении двух соседних элементов, поэтому требуется предварительная сортировка:

```js
let data = [
  {'time': '21:30'},
  {'time': '21:30'},
  {'time': '21:30'},
  {'name': 'ivan'},
  {'name': 'ivan'},  
];

let result = [];
let odd = true;

data.sort((a, b) => JSON.stringify(a).localeCompare(JSON.stringify(b)));

let last = data.reduce(function(a, b) {
  if (JSON.stringify(a) == JSON.stringify(b)) odd = !odd;
  else odd ? result.push(a) : odd = true;
  return b;
});

if (odd) result.push(last);

console.log(result);
```